# System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, future

I am trying to do a salesforce integration US Census. When I run the below code I am getting following error

> "System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"

I have a self signed certificate and i am using that in the code. I need help in fixing this error. Am I missing anything please guide me to fix this issue.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/address?street=4600+Silver+Hill+Road&city=Washington&state=DC&zip=20233&benchmark=4&vintage=4&format=json');
req.setMethod('GET');
System.debug('** The URL ** '+req);
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('** HTTP Request Output **** '+res);
```

I am getting this error in when i run the code anonymous block:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a certificate?

Comment: hi @kurunve, I followed this url https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72950/io-exception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs_http.htm

Comment: But as for me it works without certificate (with commented 4th line)

Comment: @kurunve did you added any setting ?

Comment: Nope, just run your code but without certificate

Comment: @kurunve your right. Its working for me in my personal developer instance but not in developer sandbox. I checked all the settings everything looks good.

Comment: @kurunve : This is a known issue on gov cloud https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BFrQAM. Now i need to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

***Hi,

This turns out to be a mutual TLS issue that you may want to look at these configurations first before digging more.
Check your certificate if it’s properly signed, not expired, and active. Check the named credentials to make sure it has the right certificate associated. if both these are good, then check the target server, if it’s accepting your cert. A quick check on these things could get things cleared.***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).